# Firefox with Vue.js redirecting to a wrong route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox, vue-router

I need to jump to one of my page in a Vue.js project from another website to do the login, and then jumps back with token.
But now I encountered an issue with redirecting on Firefox.
This was the link I was trying to go:
`https://www.host.com/admin/#/LoginPage?loginrul=selectportal.html%23%2Fsphome&type=login`
But this is where Firefox actually taken me to:
`https://www.host.cn/admin/#/sphome`
What confuses me is that **this issue appears only on Firefox**, I will not encounter it both on Chrome nor IE.
It also does not appear when I enter the URL manually.
Any help will be appreciated.
[image: the navigate message does not match with the url]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Firefox selects the last decoded part of your url. `%23%2F` is the same as `#/`, while `%23` is `#` and `%2F` `/`. So for Firefox not `/LoginPage?loginrul=selectportal.html%23%2Fsphome&type=login` is the url, instead it´s `#/sphome&type=login`. That this part is decoded doesn´t mean it doesn´t get interpreted by a browser.

Maybe Chrome and IE using the first hash as their entry. But that was just lucky. You need to get rid of your hash, you can achieve this by adding this to your router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history'
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Will try this out!

Comment: Hi Steven, I've encountered to some new problems, but it worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @Yukiteru Good, that it helped you getting forward. If you faced something new, just ask a new question and I/we will help you.

Comment: It's so nice for you to say that, I really appreciate it! ...And actually, I do have another question, and it's about Vue.js and Firefox too, I would be very very thankful if you could take a look at it too!